# How do I properly deploy Eclipse OSGI plug-in that I created?

Tags: java, eclipse, primefaces, eclipse-plugin, osgi

I followed instruction on the following page to convert the primefaces jar library to OSGi plug-in and added it as one of the required plug-ins in my OSGi bundle. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJarToPlugin/article.html#jar-files-without-osgi-meta-data

However, when I deployed my OSGi bundle, I got `missing requirement` which I suppose because I never deploy the new plug-in to glassfish. How do I deploy that?

Here's the stacktrace I got, in case the error was due to something else:

```
[#|2016-09-12T11:14:04.150+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=85;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while loading the app : org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle test.osgi.primefaces [293]: Unable to resolve 293.0: missing requirement [293.0] osgi.wiring.bundle; (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=org.primefaces.osgi)(bundle-version>=1.0.0))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle test.osgi.primefaces [293]: Unable to resolve 293.0: missing requirement [293.0] osgi.wiring.bundle; (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=org.primefaces.osgi)(bundle-version>=1.0.0))
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3826)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1868)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:944)
        at org.glassfish.extras.osgicontainer.OSGiDeployedBundle.startBundle(OSGiDeployed
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says that your test bundle requires the bundle with symbolic name org.primefaces.osgi. So you also need to deploy this bundle.

Comment: A quick google gives me this:
deploy --type=osgi MyBundle.jar